# How to check entering number in edittext after decimal is only 5 or 0

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I want to check length of entered number while entering the value in edittext. Also i want to check user can only able to enter 5 or 0 after decimal point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use TextWatcher.  Use this documentation.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Then in OnTextChanged you can check what the length of the edit text is. I don't know how to check if the decimal point ends with 0 or 5. Sorry about that. You should ask a separate question about that. Hope this helps.